# New React project

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a new React project, it has no errors, but somehow when I open it on localhost:8080 instead of showing Test, it shows it's directories.

[github project link](https://github.com/bmpezzi/todo)

Answer (score 1):

Normally react runs on port 3000 by default.

if you are running
`npm run dev`
and it is also serving on port 8080 then you have a problem with your webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

React application doesn't run keeping your project on localhost port. You'll need to start the project using:

```
npm start
```

It will run the application on 3000 port by default.

If you want to run it on localhost port (xampp, etc.), then you'll need to build it first:

```
npm build
```

And then keep the built files there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks proper. Everything seems to be in place. How are you running it? Maybe that is where the problem is. If you feel you're running it right, maybe try changing the port where it runs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my webpack.config.js. I had this:

devServer: {
port: 8080,
contenBase: './public'
}

just fixed the contenBase to contentBase. I know it sounds stupid but. How was I supposed to notice it around dozes of lines.